# The natural numbers are not open.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I am wondering if someone can let me know if my solution is correct. I want to show that the natural numbers are not open. My work so far,

To show that the natural numbers are not open we must find a neighborhood $V_\epsilon(a),\;a\in \mathbb{N}. $ Such that $V_\epsilon(a)\not\subset \mathbb{N}$. Take $a=1$ and $\epsilon = 2$, $V_2(1) = (-1,3)\not\subset\mathbb{N}$. Is this enough to show that the set is not open? Or do I have to be more general? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean open in the usual topology on $\Bbb R$?  I think you have to show a point of $\Bbb N$ has *no* neighborhood in $\Bbb N$, for any $\epsilon$ (not that, as you showed, there is *a* neighborhood not in $\Bbb N$ with a particular $\epsilon$)

Comment: Yes, the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$. So I need to show that every neighborhood around 1 is not in $\mathbb{N}$, correct, J. W. Tanner?

Comment: That would do it

Answer (score 2):

You have to show that for the point 1 there does not exist ANY epsilon-neighbourhood. So basically try showing that $V_\epsilon (1) $ is not a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ for all $\epsilon>0$